# Separating Trigger into a Helper Class

Tags: apex, trigger

I got the following trigger and I need to separate it out to a helper class as a method and call that method in the trigger.

```
trigger UpdateCurrency on Flow__c (before insert) 

{
    List<Id> opportunityIds = new List<Id>();
    Map<Id, String> oppIdCurrencyCode = new Map<Id, String>();
    for(Flow__c ir : System.Trigger.new) {
        opportunityIds.add(ir.opportunity__c);
    }
    for(Opportunity opp : [Select CurrencyIsoCode from Opportunity where Id in: opportunityIds]) {
        oppIdCurrencyCode.put(opp.Id, opp.CurrencyIsoCode);
    }
    for(Flow__c ir : System.Trigger.new) {
        ir.CurrencyIsoCode = oppIdCurrencyCode.get(ir.opportunity__c);
    }
```

I want to make the above trigger a method in a class so that I can call the method in the trigger as below.

```
trigger UpdateCurrency on flow__c (before insert) {
if (Trigger.isInsert){
    UpdateCurrencyHelper.ValidateCurrency(trigger.new);}
```

How can I put the trigger to a helper class as a method ?

Comment: Have you made your helper class yet? Have you created a method stub where you're looking to place your current logic into? As is, I don't know if there's any answer other than "make a class, add a method, and copy/paste your current code". Have you tried to do this and ran into a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

i was able to complete this in the end. See below

Trigger :

```
********************************************************************
 * UpdateCurrencyInsert 
 *
 * Before Insert trigger on Flow
 ********************************************************************/
trigger UpdateCurrencyInsert on Flow__c (before insert) 
{
  FlowUtils.ValidateCurrencyUpdate(Trigger.new);
}
```

Class :

```
public class FlowUtils {

   public static void ValidateCurrencyUpdate(List<Flow__c> flows ) {


      List<Id> opportunityIds = new List<Id>();
      Map<Id, String> oppIdCurrencyCode = new Map<Id, String>();
      for (Flow__c Flow: flows ) {
          opportunityIds.add(Flow.opportunity__c);
      }

      for(Opportunity opp : [Select CurrencyIsoCode from Opportunity where Id in: opportunityIds]) {
        oppIdCurrencyCode.put(opp.Id, opp.CurrencyIsoCode);
      }

      for(Flow__c flow : flows) {
        flow.CurrencyIsoCode = oppIdCurrencyCode.get(flow.opportunity__c);
      }


   }
 }
```